# How to implement a friending system in firebase

Tags: firebase

I have just started working with firebase for a backend of a application I'm working on and one piece I can't get my head around is how to handle friending system. How would you go about implementing this feature in a service like firebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each user could have an ID (if you authorize the users, you could use auth.uid for the ID). In the Firebase, for each user, you would list all the IDs of the people the person has friended. You could also have a category for people who has friended the person.

A Firebase might look like this:

```
users
|
--- #00922784
|   |
|   --- friends
|   |   |
|   |   --- #19324819
|   |   |
|   |   --- #01993882
|   |
|   --- followers
|       |
|       --- #19324819
|
--- #19324819
    |
    --- friends
    |   |
    |   --- #00922784
    |
    --- followers
        |
        --- #19324819
```

etc.

You could also store the person's name, like this:

```
--- #19324819
    |
    --- friends
    |   |
    |   --- #00922784
    |
    --- followers
    |  |
    |  --- #19324819
    |
    --- name
        |
        --- TimothyS
```